# make person enter something before executing command(Tkinter,Python,Selenium)

Tags: python, selenium, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
from selenium import webdriver
class Practice():
    def __init__(self):

        self.name = StringVar()

        self.nameLabel = Label(root, text="Name")
        self.nameEntry = Entry(root, textvariable= self.name)

        self.submitButton = Button(root,text="Submit",command=self.submit)

        self.nameLabel.pack()
        self.nameEntry.pack()
        self.submitButton.pack()


    def submit(self):

        while self.name.get() == "":
            messagebox.showerror(title="No name",message="No name")
        driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        driver.get("http://stackoverflow.com/")


root = Tk()
b= Practice()
root.mainloop()
```

WARNING= This causes an infinite loop close the program to exit

So I was wondering guys. You know how there are some forms wherein if you don't fill up a field. like for example your name. it'll show a message box saying you didn't put your name and you exit that messagebox and then fill up your name and after you hit submit the messagebox won't popup anymore.

Now my question is how do we recreate that?

the script I have above does that kinda. but will loop forever and won't allow the user to go back and put his name on the name entrybox.

also changing this while loop to an if:

```
def submit(self):

            if self.name.get() == "":
                messagebox.showerror(title="No name",message="No name")
            driver = webdriver.Firefox()
            driver.get("http://stackoverflow.com/")
```

doesn't cause an infinte loop but still executes the command:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://stackoverflow.com/")
```

TL:DR
how can we prevent the command from being executed if the name entrybox is empty and how to prevent the messagebox from looping forever?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do the check once. Each time the user clicks the submit button the check will again be performed.

```
def submit(self):

    if self.name.get() == "":
        messagebox.showerror(title="No name",message="No name")
        return

    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.get("http://stackoverflow.com/")
```

Comment: The key here is `return`. Also, the check can be `if not self.name.get():`.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 oh so thats how you do it. darn I missed one word and it was `return`. what exactly is returned here?

Comment: Nothing (literally, `None`). You just want the function to end there.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 woah ok. Man I need to learn so much more about python thank you very much. So if you return none than the command next to it wont be executed? I never knew that

Comment: The `return` statement ends the function, returning something (or `None`, as here) to whatever called it. For example, `webdriver.Firefox()` will `return` a driver of some kind, which you save as `driver`. Here, it just stops the function, since it doesn't generally make sense to return a value to a `tkinter` widget.

Comment: Oh right. of course. because it's a widget so a value shouldn't be returned like in this case. Thank you very much man. I learned something new today